# Rails - Sort dropdown list with the string "9th" coming before "10th"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line of code for sorting the records inside a dropdown list:

```
<% @classrooms.order(:classroom_name).each do |classroom| %>
```

it works fine most of the time except that in quite a few cases I have the following values in the dropdown:

```
10th Grade - Smith
11th Grade - Johnson
12th Grade - Roberts
9th Grade - Oneil
```

The problem is that the system is assuming it should be first sorting on the first character, then the next and so on.

Is there an easy way to handle this without stripping out the numbers from the letters, sorting the numbers separately and concatenating them back together? Thanks.

Comment: Creating a Ruby class for classrooms and having the grade, teacher, and other information as variables is a more flexible approach. You can then use `ordinalize` to add the 'th', 'nd', 'rd' to the numbers (called ordinals).

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to do it would be by using `sort_by`

```
classrooms = ['10th', '9th', '11th', '8th']
=> ["10th", "9th", "11th", "8th"]
list = %w{8th 9th 10th 11th}
=> ["8th", "9th", "10th", "11th"]
classrooms.sort_by { |e| list.index(e) || list.length }
=> ["8th", "9th", "10th", "11th"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you will have classroom name in specified format only then you can use **postgres substring** and order on numbers. Like this:

```
@classrooms.order("(substring(classroom_name, '(^[0-9]+)'))::int")
```

Above query will order your results by classroom_names first numbers substring that is 10, 11, 12, 9.

But, I will recommend you to break the column and introduce new column like **grade**. because your **classroom_name**  contains more information than just a name.